# Register multiple IInterceptor in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is there any way to register multiple IInterceptor in nhibernate

this dose not work in hhibernate 3.1.0.4000

```
config.SetInterceptor(new ContextAwareInterceptor());
config.SetInterceptor(new ContextAwareCommandInterceptor());
config.SetInterceptor(new SqlInterceptor());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A session can only have one interceptor.

You should look into [Events](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events) instead.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 7):

You can pull this off by using a composite interceptor. The following is an implementation that's worked for me. Just be aware that if you have multiple interceptors that implement a method that returns a value (Like `GetEntity()`), in some cases the first one is returned and others (Like `FindDirty()` and `OnPrepareStatement()`) the results are combined. Full listing with tests [here](https://gist.github.com/mikeobrien/cad8e66456d45ff0a5e2).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.SqlCommand;
using NHibernate.Type;

public class CompositeInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IInterceptor> _interceptors;

    public CompositeInterceptor(IEnumerable<IInterceptor> interceptors)
    {
        _interceptors = interceptors.ToList();
    }

    public void AfterTransactionBegin(ITransaction tx)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.AfterTransactionBegin(tx));
    }

    public void AfterTransactionCompletion(ITransaction tx)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.AfterTransactionCompletion(tx));
    }

    public void BeforeTransactionCompletion(ITransaction tx)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.BeforeTransactionCompletion(tx));
    }

    public int[] FindDirty(object entity, object id, object[] currentState, 
        object[] previousState, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        var results = _interceptors
            .Select(interceptor => interceptor.FindDirty(entity, id,
                currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types))
            .Where(result => result != null)
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();
        return !results.Any() ? null : results;
    }

    public object GetEntity(string entityName, object id)
    {
        return _interceptors
            .Select(interceptor => interceptor.GetEntity(entityName, id))
            .FirstOrDefault(result => result != null);
    }

    public string GetEntityName(object entity)
    {
        return _interceptors
            .Select(interceptor => interceptor.GetEntityName(entity))
            .FirstOrDefault(result => result != null);
    }

    public object Instantiate(string entityName, EntityMode entityMode, object id)
    {
        return _interceptors
            .Select(interceptor => interceptor.Instantiate(entityName, entityMode, id))
            .FirstOrDefault(result => result != null);
    }

    public bool? IsTransient(object entity)
    {
        return _interceptors
            .Select(interceptor => interceptor.IsTransient(entity))
            .FirstOrDefault(result => result != null);
    }

    public void OnCollectionRecreate(object collection, object key)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.OnCollectionRecreate(collection, key));
    }

    public void OnCollectionRemove(object collection, object key)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.OnCollectionRemove(collection, key));
    }

    public void OnCollectionUpdate(object collection, object key)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.OnCollectionUpdate(collection, key));
    }

    public void OnDelete(object entity, object id, object[] state, 
        string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.OnDelete(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types));
    }

    public bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, object id, object[] currentState, 
        object[] previousState, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        return _interceptors.Count(interceptor => interceptor.OnFlushDirty(
            entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types)) > 0;
    }

    public bool OnLoad(object entity, object id, object[] state, 
        string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        return _interceptors.Count(interceptor => interceptor.OnLoad(
            entity, id, state, propertyNames, types)) > 0;
    }

    public SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        return _interceptors.Aggregate(sql, (current, interceptor) => 
            interceptor.OnPrepareStatement(current));
    }

    public bool OnSave(object entity, object id, object[] state, 
        string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        return _interceptors.Count(interceptor => interceptor.OnSave(
            entity, id, state, propertyNames, types)) > 0;
    }

    public void PostFlush(ICollection entities)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.PostFlush(entities));
    }

    public void PreFlush(ICollection entities)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.PreFlush(entities));
    }

    public void SetSession(ISession session)
    {
        _interceptors.ForEach(x => x.SetSession(session));
    }
}
```